# Problemas para carregar "mssql" no PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma conexão PHP com o SQL Server 2008 mas o servidor retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

Procurei em muitos lugares e todos dizem para ir em PHP.ini e retirar o comentário da linha:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

Mas meu arquivo php.ini não tem essa linha.

Este é meu código atual, mas já tentei vários outros:

```
<?php 
   mssql_connect("192.168.2.7", "sa", "5c@n9r1n7#@dm") or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o servidor"); 
   mssql_select_db("fd_585b0f87") or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados"); 
   mssql_close(); 
   print "Conexão OK"; 
?>
```

Já tentei esse também:

```
<?php 
   $server = "192.168.2.7"; 
   $banco="fd_585b0f87"; 
   $user ="sa"; 
   $senha="5c@n9r1n7#@dm"; 
   $conexao = mssql_connect($server,$user,$senha); 
   $conexao = mssql_select_db("$banco", $conexao); 

   if($conexao){ 
      echo "conexao Certa"; 
   } 
?>
```

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Acrescente a linha no php.ini se ela nao existe. Se não funcionar, provavelmente você terá que instalar essa biblioteca. Mas primeiro, experimente só acrescentar a linha. E isso pra PHP no windows, pq no linux e similares nao é DLL, é SO.

Comment: Segundo a documentação oficial (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mssql.installation.php) você tem que compilar o PHP com o mssql, mas isso é +ou- um chute, nunca usei m$ sql server com PHP.

Comment: Primeiro verifique se existe a php_mssql.dll, se não existir ele não irá conseguir carregar. Se estiver usando o linux deveria ser php_mssql.so em geral isso costumar vir junto com o php, crie uma página php e coloque o comando: <?php  phpinfo(); ?> acesse essa página, isso exibirá tudo o que o seu php suporta, procure nessa página informações sobre o mssql.

Comment: Já utilizei o PHP com MSSQL e aconteceu o mesmo erro, resolvi através do link abaixo. Veja se ajuda, se sim posto como resposta para não ficar só o link: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/395466-resolvidoerro-ao-conectar-php-a-base-de-dados-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser necessário você atualizar o driver do php para acessar o mssql, você pode baixar o driver atualizado direto no site da Microsoft ([Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)) você também tem a opção de usar o [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) para se conectar o mssql. [No site do php na parte do mssql](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/book.mssql.php) existe além da sintaxe de como utilizar, vários comentários sobre compatibilidade e informações sobre a depreciação de comandos ao final da página além de links de solução que podem ser esclarecedores e acabar servindo como solução, mas creio que só atualizar já deve resolver.

Verifique se você tem a biblioteca necessária para usar o mssql, ou seja, se o arquivo dll ou so (dependendo do sistema operacional) existe fisicamente, crie um arquivo para ler o que o seu servidor suporta

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

Após criar o arquivo verifique se entre os recursos suportados está presente o mssql.
Uma outra coisa que pode auxiliar muito é verificar o arquivo de log.